# rank(T) = dim(ran(T)) = 1

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am working with a finite rank operator T, where $Tx = \langle x, y \rangle z$, and I am trying to show a sub-result before moving forward and I would appreciate clarification.

Let H be a Hilbert space. 
If $T: H→H$ is a linear mapping. How can I show that T has rank = 1?

I know that $rank(T) = dim(R(T))$, which would mean that where $R(T)$ is the range of T.

Comment: When you say $Tx = \langle x,y \rangle z$, are $y, z$ predetermined parts of $T$? (As in, are they fixed?)

Comment: Are $y,z$ fixed members of $H$ here? If so, we see that $R(T) = \{\alpha z : \alpha \in \mathbb C\}$ which is clearly one dimensional since if is spanned by the vector $z$.

Comment: Yes, they are fixed members. The range of T is one dimensional, and so I see that I was over thinking. It is straightforward then to say that since I know, in my case, that $ran(T) = span{x_0}$, for $x_0$ not equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $T$ is linear. Suppose that $y, z$ are both non-zero. (Otherwise the range is $\{0\}$, so the rank is $0$.)

$Tx = \langle x,y \rangle z = \alpha_x z$ where $\alpha_x$ is a real number depending on $x$.
This means the range of $T$ is a subset of $\{\alpha z: z\in H\}$. This means the rank is less than or equal to $1$. However, our conditions require that the rank is also greater than $0$. Therefore it must have rank equal to $1$.